# Longtable Misplaced \noalign errors

Tags: tables, line-breaking, longtable

I'm using longtable to create a my table. I am getting the table I want but I'm getting this error:

> Misplaced \noalign. You have used a \hline command in the wrong place,
>   probably outside a table. If the \hline command is written inside a
>   table, try including \ before it.

Here is the code of my table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\caption{Tableau récapitulatif des modèles de prédiction de l’évolution de communautés dans la littérature} \label{tab:long} \\

\hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Méthode}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Entrée}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Algorithme}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Validation} } & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Résultats}} \\ \hline 
\endfirsthead
\hline \multicolumn{5}{|r|}{{(Voir la page suivante)}} \\ \hline
\endfoot

\hline \hline
\endlastfoot
\parbox{62pt}{\raggedright 
\cite{Goldberg2011}
} & \parbox{88pt}{\raggedright 
\addlinespace
\textbullet{} Métriques significatives : la densité, l’intersection et la taille du noyau d’une communauté.
\addlinespace
} & \parbox{79pt}{\raggedright 
\textbullet{ }Prédicteur de durée de vie d’une communauté.
} & \parbox{71pt}{\raggedright 
\textbullet{} Leave-one-out cross validation.
} & \parbox{78pt}{\raggedright 
\addlinespace
\textbullet{} Les communautés intenses, petites et stables ont les plus longues durées de vie.
\addlinespace
} \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

How can I escape those errors?

Comment: what you like to achieve with `\addlinespace`? more vertical space around cells?

Comment: Yes. I want to get margins.

Comment: This can be obtain with `makecell` package. See my answer.

Comment: Please always cite the full error message from the log.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not clear to me, what you like to achieve with `\addlinespace` (erors done with your use is explained in *David Carlisle* answer). More vertical space around cells? For more items in one cell, I would use (adopted for use in table) `\itemize` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[labelfont=bf,skip=3pt]{caption}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, longtable, makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\normalsize}
    \usepackage{enumitem}       % for nice list
\newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{1}% <-- defined new list
\setlist[tabitemize]{nosep,     % <-- new list setup
                     topsep     = 0pt       ,
                     partopsep  = 0pt       ,
                     leftmargin = *         ,
                     label      = $\bullet$ ,
                     before     = \vspace{-\baselineskip},
                     after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
                     }

\begin{document}
{   \setcellgapes{3pt}
    \makegapedcells
\begin{longtable}{|l|
                *{3}{>{\RaggedRight}p{98pt}|}
                     >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{98pt}|}
    \caption{Tableau réapitulatif des modèles de prédiction de l’évolution de communautés dans la littérature}
\label{tab:long} \\
    \hline 
\thead{Méthode} &   \thead{Entrée}  &   \thead{Algorithme}    
    &   \thead{Validation}  &   \thead{Résultats}       \\ 
    \hline
\endfirsthead
    \hline 
\multicolumn{5}{|r|}{{(Voir la page suivante)}}         \\ 
    \hline
\endfoot
    \hline \hline
\endlastfoot
\cite{Goldberg2011}
    &   \begin{tabitemize}
        \item   Métriques significatives : la densité, l’intersection et la taille du noyau d’une communauté.
        \end{tabitemize}
    &   \begin{tabitemize}
        \item   Prédicteur de durée de vie d’une communauté.
        \item   Prédicteur de durée de vie d’une communauté.
        \end{tabitemize}
    &   \begin{tabitemize}
        \item   Leave-one-out cross validation.
        \item   Leave-one-out cross validation.
        \item   Leave-one-out cross validation.
        \end{tabitemize}
    &   \begin{tabitemize}
        \item   Les communautés intenses, petites et stables ont les plus longues durées de vie.
        \end{tabitemize}                                                            \\
    \hline
\end{longtable}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

the full error message is

```
! Misplaced \noalign.
\addlinespace ->\noalign 
                         {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \@ifnextchar [{\@addspace }{\@addsp...
l.30 }
       & \parbox{79pt}{\raggedright
```

which shows the problem is the `\addlinespace`

`\addlinespace` has to be at the start of a table row, you can not use it inside a `\parbox`.

Also do not surround `longtable` by a `center` environment (it has no effect on its horizontal position, just adds spurious vertical space)

I guess the intended layout is something like

[image]

although I would use `p` columns not `m` so the parboxes are top aligned and the bullets line up.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable,array}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}
\begin{longtable}{|l|
>{\raggedright}m{75pt}|
>{\raggedright}m{75pt}|
>{\raggedright}m{75pt}|
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{75pt}|}
\caption{Tableau réapitulatif des modèles de prédiction de l’évolution de communautés dans la littérature} \label{tab:long} \\

\hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Méthode}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Entrée}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Algorithme}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Validation} } & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Résultats}} \\ \hline 
\endfirsthead
\hline \multicolumn{5}{|r|}{{(Voir la page suivante)}} \\ \hline
\endfoot

\hline \hline
\endlastfoot
\cite{Goldberg2011}
&\textbullet{} Métriques significatives : la densité, l’intersection et la taille du noyau d’une communauté.
 & 
\textbullet{ }Prédicteur de durée de vie d’une communauté.
& 
\textbullet{} Leave-one-out cross validation.
& 
\textbullet{} Les communautés intenses, petites et stables ont les plus longues durées de vie.
\\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So where to put `\addlinespace` ?

Comment: well start by deleting it as it is in error, I could not guess the intended layout (or why you have parboxes at all rather than a `p` column.) so I did not suggest any fix other than deleting the commands that are in error

Comment: After deleting it the margins disappear. I would appreciate it if you could suggest a fix, even if that changes the table style.

Comment: @Joker00 Try `\strut\newline` before and `\newline` after.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Sorry, before and after what?

Comment: @Joker00 I mean at the same places where you have used `\addlinespace` but the one that comes before the text of the box needs the `\strut` in addition to the `\newline`

Comment: @AndrewSwann I get `there is no line here to end` error

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you! How to add multiple bullets in one cell?

Comment: @Joker00 you could just start another paragraph (leave a blank line) then start with \textbullet as you have done already but better would be to remove all the `\textbullet` and use an `itemize` environment and `\item`

Comment: @Joker00 as I say above your comments make it clear that you should be using `itemize` so probably you should accept zarko's answer.